# JavaScript - Append option element to a select element not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to append an option element to a select element using JavaScript but I can't get it to work. I broke the code into pieces and called `console.log()` everywhere I imagined a possible mistake, but everything seems to be working fine, except the appendChild method.

I have also tried with: `select.add(new option('value1', 'value2')`but it didn't work.

**The Javascript Code:**

```
var divTo = document.getElementById('selectProduct');
console.log(divTo);
if (whereTo == 'selectProduct'){
    console.log('inside if loop');
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
        console.log('inside for loop')
        console.log('products[i] = ' +products[i]);
        var addedOption = new Option();
        addedOption.label = products[i];
        console.log("addedOption label = "+addedOption.label);                  
        divTo.appendChild(addedOption);
        console.log("divTo constructor = "+divTo.constructor.name);
        console.log("addedOptionConstructor = "+addedOption.constructor.name);

 // also tried: divTo.options.add(new Option("valor1", "valor2")); instead of appendChild

 // also tried: addedOption.text instead of addedOption.label


    }           
}
```

**The console logs:**

```
inside if loop
inside for loop
products[i] = Armada Argentina
addedOption label = Armada Argentina
divTo constructor = HTMLSelectElement
addedOptionConstructor = HTMLOptionElement
<select class=​"selectfield" id=​"selectProduct" name=​"product">​</select>​
```

Could someone help me out?.

PS: I'm really new to programming. I'm sorry if the mistake is evident.

Comment: `whereTo` is not the same as `divTo` - check your developer tools console for errors - change whereTo in the if condition to fix

Comment: then check against `divTo.id` - then add some CONTENT (not a label) to the option so it displays something

Comment: Nothing to do with your error, but consider doing `new Option(optionText, optionValue)` so you set its properties all in one go.

Comment: @JaromandaX whereTo is the function parameter, I need to have it there because of external reaseons, anyway, from the logs I can see that the statement in the `if` statement evaluated to true, because the function goes inside the loop (and prints 'inside the if loop' in the console).

Comment: @JaromandaX I will try the `divTo.id` solution, thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an `option` element to a `select` box dynamically, right?

See this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9jLof2n/)

Comment: A link isn't an answer. If you think this is a duplicate, mark it as such.

Comment: @philantrovert I tried your answer, and now I get the first option field appended, but only the first. If I comment `$("#mySelect").append($('<option>', {value: 4, text: 4}));` it stops working again. In the console I'm getting a reference error in that line. I tried loading Jquery and the error dissapears, but then no `option` field is added to the `select box`

Comment: It was already on `onload="function()"` I tried switching that for `$(document).ready()` yet it makes no difference. @philantrovert

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
 var divTo = document.getElementById('selectProduct');
if (whereTo == 'selectProduct') {
    console.log('inside if loop');
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
        var addedOption = document.createElement("option");
        addedOption.text = products[i];
        divTo.add(addedOption);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vaibhav , but it's not really working. Trying different things I just discovered that it works only if the program goes through the loop one time. If it goes two or more times, it stop working (your solutions, and the others). I've added this fact as a edit to the question.

Comment: This code works fine for n number of loops.
are you calling this code on Onload ?

Comment: It's in `onload` indeed. It also think it should work, but it really doesn't. Is it possible that it's not working for some server configuration? @Vaibhav

Comment: Can you make some html content and post , then i could help you

Answer (score 0):

`createSelect()` creates a select and options by passing 2 equal length arrays and a target element to append to.

**Signature**

> `createSelect(textArray, valueArray, target)`

**Parameters**

> - **textArray**: An array of strings--each string set to an option's content--**length must be equal to the length of valueArray**.
> - **valueArray**: An array of strings--each string set to an option's value--**length must be equal to the length of textArray**.
> - **target**: A string--syntax same as CSS and jQuery selector.

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
var txt = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE'];
var val = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

function createSelect(textArray, valueArray, target) {
  var tgt = document.querySelector(target);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  var qty = textArray.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.textContent = textArray[i];
    opt.value = valueArray[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
  }
  tgt.appendChild(sel);
}

createSelect(txt, val, "body");
```

For `onload`, wrap it in another function:

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
function init() {

  var txt = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE'];
  var val = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  function createSelect(textArray, valueArray, target) {
    var tgt = document.querySelector(target);
    var sel = document.createElement('select');
    var qty = textArray.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.textContent = textArray[i];
      opt.value = valueArray[i];
      sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
    tgt.appendChild(sel);
  }

  createSelect(txt, val, "body");
}

window.onload = init;
```